Rolling Sum, with periods given from Pandas Column
Trying to calculate in pandas the rolling sum of Values in Column A, with lookback periods given in Column B and results of rolling sums stored in Column C.
Index | Column A | Column B || Column C |
      | -------- | -------- || -------- |
  0   |     1    |    1     ||    1     |
  1   |     2    |    2     ||    3     |
  2   |     1    |    3     ||    4     |
  3   |     3    |    2     ||    4     |
  4   |     2    |    4     ||    8     |

For example, for last row, the rolling sum should sum the last 4 values from Column A, since 4 is given in column B.
Avoiding loops would be optimal.
Although a simple task, I haven't managed to come up with a solution.

What have you tried? This should be really easy to do with a loop over B, though that's not optimal.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can also [edit] to add details.

What is the range of values for B?

Wjandrea, thank you, certainly will do.
I had tried to manipulate the data to combine with groupby: but didn't work.
Nick, the lookback range is very limited and is not a constraint since the amount of data is material-thank you.

Since your rolling sums depend on all values, you will have to compute one per window. This can be done using numpy and indexing lookup:
import numpy as np

idx, vals = pd.factorize(df['B'])

df['C'] = np.vstack([
    df['A'].rolling(v, min_periods=1).sum()
    for v in vals
])[idx, np.arange(len(df))]

Output:
   A  B    C
0  1  1  1.0
1  2  2  3.0
2  1  3  4.0
3  3  2  4.0
4  2  4  8.0

Variant if you want to use different aggregation functions at once (here sum and mean for the demo, although D could also be computed as C/B):
import numpy as np

idx, vals = pd.factorize(df['B'])

df[['C', 'D']] = np.dstack([
    df['A'].rolling(v, min_periods=1)
           .agg(['sum', 'mean'])
    for v in vals
])[np.arange(len(df)), :, idx]

Output:
   A  B    C         D
0  1  1  1.0  1.000000
1  2  2  3.0  1.500000
2  1  3  4.0  1.333333
3  3  2  4.0  2.000000
4  2  4  8.0  2.000000

Reproducible input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,3,2],
                   'B': [1,2,3,2,4]})


I posted an answer using the .rolling API if you want to see it :) I believe it'll be faster than this at scale since it uses Cython to do the heavy lifting instead of a list comp.

@wjandrea nice one, I have already used this kind of approach, it's particularly interesting if you write a module. For a single use that's maybe a lot of code.

The factorized categories(vals) is not at all necessary as the lookback window values are numerical.@mozway

As stated in DataFrame.rolling, you can provide a BaseIndexer subclass. There's a lot of boilerplate involved to fit the .rolling API, but the result is really elegant:
>>> c = df['A'].rolling(VariableSizeWindow(df['B'])).sum()
>>> df.assign(C=c)
   A  B    C
0  1  1  1.0
1  2  2  3.0
2  1  3  4.0
3  3  2  4.0
4  2  4  8.0

Class code
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class VariableSizeWindow(BaseIndexer):
    def __init__(self, sizes: pd.Series | np.ndarray | list[int]):
        super().__init__()
        self.sizes = sizes.values if isinstance(sizes, pd.Series) else sizes
        # NOTE: `window_size` would seem to be the natural
        # choice instead of `sizes`, but if `window_size` is set,
        # Pandas assumes it's convertible to int and assigns it to
        # `min_periods`, which is not valid here.

    def get_window_bounds(
        self,
        num_values: int = 0,
        min_periods: int | None = None,  # ignored
        center: bool | None = None,  # Not implemented
        closed: str | None = None,  # Not implemented
        step: int | None = None,  # Not implemented
    ) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        if center is not False:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "center not implemented for variable size window")
        if closed is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "closed not implemented for variable size window")
        if step is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "step not implemented for variable size window")

        start = np.arange(num_values, dtype=np.int64) - self.sizes + 1
        end = np.arange(num_values, dtype=np.int64) + 1
        return start, end

Comparing with mozway's variation (different aggregation functions at once):
>>> df['A'].rolling(VariableSizeWindow(df['B'])).agg(['sum', 'mean'])
   sum      mean
0  1.0  1.000000
1  3.0  1.500000
2  4.0  1.333333
3  4.0  2.000000
4  8.0  2.000000


P.S. I believe it'll be really fast too since it uses Cython under the hood (pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx, specifically roll_sum()).

This is very cool. I learned something interesting today.

Here is a way using np.tril()
[a[s:].sum() for a,s in zip(
    np.tril(df['A']),
    np.arange(len(df)) - df['B'].to_numpy() + 1
 )]

or:
(np.where(
    ~(np.arange(len(df)) < (np.arange(len(df)) - df['B'].to_numpy() + 1)[:,None]),
    np.tril(df['A']),
    0)
    .sum(axis=1))

Output:
[1, 3, 4, 4, 8]


This could get very expensive in memory for a large dataframe.

Use torch to make it more efficient :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Values': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
    'Lookback_Window': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
})

# Convert columns to PyTorch tensors
values = torch.tensor(df['Values'])
lookback_window = torch.tensor(df['Lookback_Window'])

# Calculate the cumulative sum of Values
end_values = values_cumsum = torch.cumsum(values, dim=0)

# Create an array of start indices for the rolling sum
start_indices = torch.arange(len(values)) - lookback_window + 1

# Use the cumulative sum tensor to calculate the rolling sums
start_values = torch.where(start_indices > 0, values_cumsum[start_indices - 1],
                            torch.tensor(0.0))

# Fix negative start_indices by using the original cumsum values directly
rolling_sums = torch.where(start_indices < 0, values_cumsum, end_values - start_values)

# Move tensors back to CPU if necessary
rolling_sums_cpu = rolling_sums.cpu() if rolling_sums.is_cuda else rolling_sums

# Assign the rolling sums back to the DataFrame
df['Rolling_Sum'] = rolling_sums_cpu.numpy()

print(df)

Full Code :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Values': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
    'Lookback_Window': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
})

values = df['Values'].to_numpy()
lookback_window = df['Lookback_Window'].to_numpy()
values_cumsum = np.cumsum(values)

# Create an array of start indices for the rolling sum
start_indices = np.arange(len(values)) - lookback_window + 1 
start_values = np.where( start_indices > 0, values_cumsum[start_indices -1], 0 )

print(start_values)#[0 0 0 3 1]

end_values = values_cumsum = np.cumsum(values)

rolling_sums = end_values - start_values

print(rolling_sums)#[1 3 4 4 8]

# Fix negative start_indices by using the original cumsum values directly
rolling_sums[start_indices < 0] = values_cumsum[start_indices < 0]

df['Rolling_Sums'] = rolling_sums 

print(df)
"""
  Values  Lookback_Window  Rolling_Sums
0       1                1             1
1       2                2             3
2       1                3             4
3       3                2             4
4       2                4             8
"""


Mathematical Concept and Formula :


v = [v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]
The cumulative sum S of this sequence is another sequence where each element 
S_i represents the sum of all elements from v_1 to v_i:

S_i = v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_i

This can be calculated efficiently using np.cumsum in NumPy.

For each element i in the sequence, you want to calculate the rolling sum based
 on a lookback window w. This window defines how many previous elements you want 
 to include in the sum.

The mathematical formula for the rolling sum R_i at position i is:

R_i = v_i + v_{i-1} + ... + v_{i-w+1} (if i >= w)


If start_indices[i] > 0, then i >= w (valid lookback window).
 Substitute i and start_indices[i] in the rolling sum formula:

R_i = v_i + v_{i-1} + ... + v_{i-w+1}

The conditional statement essentially achieves this by:
cumsum[i]  - cumsum[start_indices[i] - 1] = 
(v_1 + ... + v_i) - (v_1 + ... + v_{i-w}) 
= v_{i-w+1} + ... + v_i


If start_indices[i] is not greater than 0, the lookback window extends beyond the beginning. 
In such cases, the code uses 0 
to avoid negative indices and ensures the rolling sum uses the available values.


rolling_sums[i] = {
  cumsum[i] - cumsum[start_indices[i] - 1]  if start_indices[i] > 0,  # Valid lookback window (R_i)
  cumsum[i]     if start_indices[i] <= 0  # Negative or zero lookback (use all available values)
}

starting index of the lookback window for the i-th value :

start_indices[i] = i - W[i] +1 

